# C# Datagridview filter based on Combobox

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm importing data from excel to Gridview

```
        _Application importExcelToDataGridViewApp;
        _Workbook importExcelToDataGridViewWorkbook;
        _Worksheet importExcelToDataGridViewWorksheet;
        Range importExcelToDataGridViewRange;

        importExcelToDataGridViewApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL").OrderByDescending(p => p.StartTime).First();
        importExcelToDataGridViewWorkbook = importExcelToDataGridViewApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
        importExcelToDataGridViewWorksheet = importExcelToDataGridViewWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
        importExcelToDataGridViewRange = importExcelToDataGridViewWorksheet.UsedRange;  
       
        for (int excelWorkSheetRowIndex = 1; excelWorkSheetRowIndex <= importExcelToDataGridViewRange.Rows.Count; excelWorkSheetRowIndex++)
        {  country_GridView.Rows.Add(importExcelToDataGridViewWorksheet.Cells[excelWorkSheetRowIndex, 1].Value, importExcelToDataGridViewWorksheet.Cells[excelWorkSheetRowIndex, 2].Value, null);
        }
```

and then trying to filter this data using combobox

```
private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = country_GridView.DataSource;
    bs.Filter = "Country like '%" + comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() + "%'";
    country_GridView.DataSource = bs;    
}
```

But I get blank gridview when I select a country from combobox. Could you assist what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: It appears your code is "manually" adding the rows to the grid. In the first code snippet with… `country_GridView.Rows.Add(importExcelToDataGridViewWorksheet.Cells[excelWorkSheetRowIndex, 1].Value, importExcelToDataGridViewWorksheet.Cells[excelWorkSheetRowIndex, 2].Value, null);` …  Therefore, the grid does NOT have a `DataSource`…. So the code in the second code snippet… `bs.DataSource = country_GridView.DataSource;` … is going to return an “empty/null” data source.

Comment: Load your data into a DataTable, set the DataSource of the bindingSource to be the datatable. Set the DataSource of the grid to be the bindingSource. Now your filtering will work

Comment: Don't load data into a DGV in the way you've done here (DGV.Rows.Add); it's so '90s/VB6y. Keep your data in something else and bind the grid to that